# Как считается вес ссылки?

Tags: seo, индексация, поисковые-системы, продвижение

Хотел бы понять, как поисковые системы (гугл и яндекс), считают вес ссылки? Везде написано, что в принципе может ссылаться один сайт, у которого вес будет как у тысячи других.

1. Так как понять, как рассчитать вес от ссылаемого сайта, чтобы
   отобрать хороший сайт из кучи мусора, сделать с него ссылку и
   получить хороший вес?
2. И как этот вес учитывают поисковые системы (например условно: если
   вес от 500 до 100 единиц, поднять сайт на позицию в поисковой
   выдаче)?

Comment: Это внутренняя кухня поисковиков. Можете спросить у них, конечно, но они вам, скорее всего, не скажут. Это тот фрагмент поисковика, секретность которого влияет на его эффективность.

Comment: Т.е. seo-оптимизаторы сами не знают насколько эффективна будет купленная ссылка? Понятно, что можно грубо поделить сайты на совсем г и более менее норм.

Comment: точный вес не уверен, что вообще можно узнать. Но примерно прикинуть эффективность ссылки можно, используя известные метрики, такие как alexa position (только для домена), majestic, mozrank, ahrefs, semrush ранки (имеются для конкретных урлов).

Comment: это вообще ни о чем, они могут показать обратные ссылки, количество ссылок ,какой-то свой очень условный рейтинг, но не показывают влияние на поисковую выдачу